# Listen for events emitted by same Socket.IO socket

Tags: angularjs, testing, socket.io

I'm testing an Angular service that wraps Socket.IO. To do so, I need to listen for events emitted by the same socket I'm creating.

Here's the service:

```
angular.module('core').factory('SocketIOService', ['$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {

        var socket = io();

        return {

            on: function(eventName, callback) {
                var args = arguments;
                socket.on(eventName, function() {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            }

        };
    }
]);
```

And a piece of the test file (where `SocketIOService` is the service I'm creating, `socket` is the global singleton return value from `io()`, and `$rootScope` is the injected `$rootScope`):

```
it('should apply changes using $rootScope.$apply', function() {
    var rootScopeSpy = sinon.spy($rootScope, '$apply');
    SocketIOService.on('anEvent', function() {});
    socket.emit('anEvent', {});
    expect(rootScopeSpy.calledOnce).toBe(true);
});
```

But, `socket` doesn't 'hear' events for which it is listening that it also itself emits. Is there a way to emit an event and also listen for (and 'hear') that event?

Comment: Your exact question is unclear. Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

In html : You must include    < script src="http://yourdomain/socket.io/socket.io.js"> in header.

In Angular :

```
$scope.socket = new function () {
                    var self = this;
                    var socketIO;
                    var socketConfig = {};
                    self.connect = function () {
                        if (socketIO) {
                            socketIO.connect(socketConfig);
                            return;
                        }
                        socketIO = io(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ":7777", socketConfig);
                        socketIO.on('connect', function () {
                            $scope.$apply();
                        });
                        socketIO.on('your_event', function (data) {
                           // dosomething
                            $scope.$apply();
                        });

                    };
                    self.get_data = function () {
                         socketIO.emit('get_data', your data);
                    };

                }
                $scope.socket.connect();
```